# I want to egrep regular expression for multiple sets of numbers without union

Tags: regex, bash, grep

This seems like a basic question but I have done a fair amount of searching and couldn't find an answer.

Say I have many sets of numbers

9-9-9
999
123
1-23
12-3
444
55-5

I want to egrep for all numbers, now one way I could do this is set up a egrep and union the regex for all of the possibilities

egrep '[0-9][0-9[0-9]|[0-9][-][0-9][-][0-9]' and so on and so forth

Is there a way to essentially say [0-9 or NULL or -] characters in my regex?  so I could write one regex without unions like this [0-9][0-9-NULL][0-9-NULL][0-9-NULL][0-9-NULL][0-9NULL] and have it return all of the groups?

So the groups it would search would like as follows
 - first 0-9 
 - second 0-9, -, NULL
 - third 0-9, -, NULL
 - fourth 0-9, -, NULL
 - fifth 0-9, -, NULL
 - sixth 0-9, NULL

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by 'Null'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excluding the 'Null' part because I'm not quite sure what you mean by that, you use a simple regex for the egrep:

```
[0-9](-?[0-9]){2}
```

`-?` means 0 or 1 occurrence of `-`.

`{2}` means the preceding group gets repeated twice. Change it to `+` to mean at least once.

Comment: That's precisely what I was looking for but did not know how to word it.  I meant to say either '-' or nothing.

Answer (score 1):

try a regex like

```
\d[-0-9]+
```

a dash or 0-9 one or more times

**Edit**

or if it must start and end with a number (or have just one digit

```
\d[-0-9]*\d|\d
```

**Edit**

or it is always three digits

```
\d{3}|\d-\d{2}|\d{2}-d
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `egrep '[0-9][0-9\-]*'` should give the behavior you want.

Comment: Well, that is just he escape character for the '-' and that would work fine if I was interested in all numbers in the document however I want JUST numbers with the specified patters, say there was a number that was 88-1231-293742, I wouldn't want that.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `egrep '^[0-9]+(-[0-9]+){0,5}$'`

- some digits, followed by up to 5 groups of (a hyphen and digits)
- anchored at both ends of the line.

Comment: that would match "numbers" ending in a dash ( 7- for example)

Answer (score 0):

pretty sure `(-?[0-9])+` would work

it will find one or more digits that may be preceded by a `-`, although i'm also unsure on what you mean by NULL